# Canvas to URL and then save URL

Tags: jquery, html, image, canvas, uri

After click on save button its open new window with canvas ( made with html2canvas). In this new window i want to make button/link which one let me save this canvas as image (png).
CODE:

```
$(function(){
 $("#menu-save").click(function () {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "","400","400");
    var dataURL;
    html2canvas($('#leds_body'),{
        allowTaint: true,
        taintTest: false,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            canvas.id = "canvas-save";
            myWindow.document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
         }
    });

});
});
```

How to solve this? I have problem with add new element in this body and how to make dataURL(image) downloadable. I would like to know how make it with only user side and with server side.

Comment: How about you do this? `window.location = dataURL` It will open the image in a webpage. That or you can place it in an image tag `src` attribute. Then the user can just right-click and save it.

Comment: I already have it as canvas, i can click on canvas right-click and save it :) I want button/link  to download this image.

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/